# Why Solver Option is not available in Boolean Modifier Blender version 2.79.7?

Tags: modifiers

I don,t know why *Boolean Modifier* in my *Blender* version of 2.79.7 doesn't have *Solver* option, when i use *Boolean Modifier*, i get the result of my object like this[image]

I know by applying *Solver* option in the modifier, it can be solved.But the problem is in my blender there is no such option in my *Boolean Modifier* [image]

Meanwhile, people in tutorial with *Blender* version 2.79 can do that[image]

What is the problem? why *Solver* option is not available in *Boolean Modifier*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carve solver was removed in later 2.79 builds:

https://developer.blender.org/D3050